# Multisite read_more link displays URL twice

Tags: multisite

I moved a multilingual client blog from WPML to MLP adding multisite (subdomain install). 
Everything works nicely in my development environment, but the live site on my client's server now displays duplicate URLs when clicking the read_more link:

```
blog.mysite.com/blog.mysite.com/article-name/#more-xyz
```

Same thing happens if it is e.g. a category page:

```
blog.mysite.com/category/mycategory/blog.mysite.com/article-name/#more-xyz
```

This only occurs on the "**main**" website. Everything works nicely on the subdomain:

`en.blog.mysite.com` displays read_more without any problems.

Any suggestion which setting or whatever I am missing here?

edit: Added part of wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'blog.mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define( 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true );
define( 'PB_BACKUPBUDDY_MULTISITE_EXPERIMENT', true );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Comment: Look at the source: the URLs in the code are probably just without protocol. The problem is either the theme or a plugin. MultilingualPress doesn't touch the _read more_ link.

Comment: I don't expect MLP to be the problem, especially since it works nicely on the staging server (which is pretty similar to the live server, PHP versions etc.). I just don't really understand why it works on the subdomain but not on the main domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is **http://** problem.You should add **http://** in side your code. 
Like this.

```
http://blog.mysite.com/article-name/
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I deleted the http:// part above since stackexchange didn't allow me to post three links (which aren't real links anyway..)